# Java source code can not be found in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, xpages

In an xpages application a javav source code was added to the Local folder within the Lotus nsf file. Now can not be seen, and can not be found with search. The code still woking, but it is not possible to modify it.
How to get the source code back?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I used all the search functionality provided by Eclipse. Search file, java code, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name "Local" is short for "Never-put-your-own-stuff-here-because-we-remove-it-without-warning-and-it-is-actually-not-inside-the-nsf". But that name was too long even for IBM naming standards, so we call it local.

Matter of fact: the NSF does **not** contain a [local folder](http://www.addletters.com/pictures/bart-simpson-generator/3185006.htm). It is on that one machine where you added in in your workspace directory (if you are lucky). On build the code is compiled and the class file stored into the NSF (this is why it works).

You have to go back to the original machine and hope the java file is still there (or in the machines Trash bin). Create a separate source folder under web-inf and add it to the classpath (or in 8.5.3++ use the Java Design element).

If that is gone: use a [decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what we did: exported the project to the file system with directory structure. Then used jad.exe to decompile the code.

Comment: Just make sure you don't put it back into local